# How I debug an application that loads at startup / on login?

Tags: 10.10, network-manager, startup, debug, 64-bit

I am having with the NetworkManger Applet 0.8.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 AMD64. It (or NetworkManager or my wireless driver) seem to crash occasionally, which means I lose all network connectivity. How can I debug NetworkManager and the applet on startup and login? I want to know what is causing the problem so that I can fix it or file a bug report.

Edit: [This page](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager/Debugging) provides some good details about debugging the NetworkManager daemon, but I'm still having trouble with the applet (e.g. the applet crashes, I lose my connection, I restart NetworkManager and use commandline utilities, regain my connection, but no applet comes back).

Answer (score 1):

Network-Manager is started from `/etc/init.d`, as a short look reveals:

```
ls /etc/init.d/netw*
  /etc/init.d/networking
  /etc/init.d/network-interface
  /etc/init.d/network-manager
```

So you first can stop it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

I don't know how you like to debug it, with `strace`?

---

### from `man NetworkManager`

```
       --no-daemon
              Do  not  daemonize.   This  is useful for debugging, and directs log output to the controlling
              terminal in addition to syslog.

DEBUGGING
       The following environment variables are supported to help debugging.  When used in  conjunction  with
       the  "--no-daemon"  option (thus echoing PPP and DHCP helper output to stdout) these can quickly help
       pinpoint the source of connection issues.
```

So instead of strace and a simple restart, you should perhaps first stop the daemon, and then start with the above option in a console, so you can view live what's going on.

Comment: strace would be fine, or just enabling any debugging output from network-manager and redirecting it to a file. Anything that save any debugging output to a file for inspection later would work.

Comment: So `sudo strace /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` should help you. Did you do so, or are you waiting for more advice?

Comment: I would like to log ALL debugging output, from when NetworkManager starts to when and if it crashes. I want the output written to a file (permissions don't matter, I'm the only user) that can searched later.

Answer (score 0):

search the logfiles:

```
dmesg | tail
```

shortly after an incident, maybe with `tail -n 40`, see `man tail`

```
grep -i net /var/log/*log
```

if you find something interesting:

```
less /var/log/XY.log
```

If you know your wlan module name, grep for that.